# Calculate business hours between case creation and closing date (Mon-Fri 9am to 5pm)

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, custom-field, businesshours

I want to calculate the total number of business hours it took to close the case. The working hours are Monday to Friday 9am to 5pm (8 hours a day).

I wrote the following formula but it is giving incorrect number.

```
ROUND( 8 * (
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( Closed__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD( DATEVALUE( Closed__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( Closed__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 09:00:00' ), 1 ) ) )
)
)
-
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( Opened__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
MIN( 5,
MOD( DATEVALUE( Opened__c ) - DATE( 1996, 1, 1), 7 ) +
MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( Opened__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 09:00:00' ), 1) ) )
)
)
),
0 ) / 8
```

Below is the screenshot. It displays incorrect number in the field Total Case Time.

[image]

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126378/salesforce-formula-calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates