# Syntax error missing ')' in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have the following business case.

Calculate the total hours between case creation and closing time. The time should be calculated in working hours (Mon - Fri 9am to 5pm).
Pause the time when the case is put on-hold (change the case status to on-hold) and re-start the timer when the case is activated again (change the status from on-hold to something else).

I created the following fields for this purposes. The values of these fields are updated via flow when the case status is changed.

- Closed__c (Date/Time)
- TT_Case_Activation_Date__c (Date/Time)
- TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c (Date/Time)
- TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c (Date/Time)

I wrote the following formula but I cannot save it because it gives me missing ')' error:

```
IF(ISBLANK(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c), NULL,

IF(ISBLANK(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c),

ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(IF(Closed__c, NOW()) - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2),

IF(ISBLANK(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c ),
ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2),

ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2)
+
ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(IF(Closed__c, NOW())- DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2)
)

)
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question [Calculate business hours between case creation and closing date (Mon-Fri 9am to 5pm)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396064/calculate-business-hours-between-case-creation-and-closing-date-mon-fri-9am-to). You should edit your previous question to add additional information instead of making a new question.

Comment: this is a different user case. they seems similar but the requirements are slightly different.

Comment: for formulas this complex, create separate custom formula fields with good names and then combine those into the over-arching formula. So much easier to debug and read

Comment: When creating complex formulas, it's best to use a professional text editor with bracket / braces highlighting to help find missing or extra parentheses.  Look into editors like Notepad++, Sublime Text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing bracket ")" at the end of the formula. It should be added just before the last comma.

Corrected formula :-

```
IF(ISBLANK(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c), NULL,

IF(ISBLANK(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c),

ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(IF(Closed__c, NOW()) - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2),

IF(ISBLANK(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c ),
ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2),

ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_On_Hold_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( TT_Case_Activation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Activation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
), 2)
+
ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(IF(Closed__c, NOW())) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(IF(Closed__c, NOW())- DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
-
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) +
MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(TT_Case_Reactivation_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 09:00:00'), 1)))
)
)
)), 2)
)

)
```

Comment: it is still incorrect. it gives me the error:  Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

Comment: Then I'm assuming you'd add another parameter, which would be what you want the formula to return if all your nested IF statements are false.